# Capture by value in presence of non copyable locals in scope

Tags: c++, lambda

When I have a lambda function **capturing its enclosing scope by value**, why does the code [compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83f5e948f0f62204) even if there are non copyable objects in that scope ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(3); 
  auto f = [=](int j){ for(int i(0); i < j; i++) printf("blah"); }; 
  f(2); 
}
```

Comment: because youre not capturing anything? AFAIK you only capture stuff you use. youre not using anything from that scope...

Comment: @Borgleader I'm capturing the enclosing scope, no?

Comment: Not really, you *allow* the capture of everything in the surrounding scope, but since the lambda doesn't actually uses anything in the surrounding scope then nothing is actually captured.

Comment: It will only fail to compile [if you use p in the lambda.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2ff731de2f9a0ce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default capture doesn't capture every local variable in scope; only those that are used in the lambda body. You don't use `p`, and don't capture it explicitly, so it isn't captured and there's no problem.